# how can I end a function in python without using (return)?

Tags: python, python-2.7

As you know in python when you define a function, you should put `return` in code to finish function. In code like below how can I finish function:

```
def f(x) :
    if x == 0:
         print 'yes'
    print 'no'

print f(2)
```

when I run this code in the last line after printing no there will be `None` appeared ?

Comment: *"As you know in python when you define a function, you should put `return` in code to finish function."* - no, that's not accurate.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Well, it may be accurate that some readers know that, it's just that those readers are wrong. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to end the function, if the interpreter hits a line that is not on the expected indentation, the function is "automatically ended". But you try to print the return value of `f(2)`. But `f` does return `None`. So you print `None`. Don't print the function but only call the function: `f(2)`.

Calling `f(0)` will still give you `no yes` because you don't stop the execution after you checked for 0. Use an `else` clause or use `return`:

```
def f(x) :
    if x == 0:
        print 'yes'
    else:
        print 'no'

f(2)
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems that the question doesn't fit your problem.

If you do

```
print f(2)
```

it prints whatever the function returns. In your case, the function returns "nothing", so it implicitly returns `None` - which is then printed as requested.

I see two solutions:

1. Don't print what you don't want:

   ```
   def f(x) :
       if x == 0:
            print 'yes'
       else:
            print 'no'

   f(2)
   ```
2. Return something useful if you want the caller to print that:

   ```
   def f(x) :
       if x == 0:
            return 'yes'
       return 'no'

   print f(2)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are printing the return of function and you are not returning any thing and it prints `None` 
You should just call it it has a internal print that prints what you want to `print.`

Answer (score -2):

The beauty of Python is that it asks you to format code properly. What all requires to use proper indentation. All you need to do is:

```
    def f(x) :
        if x == 0:
           print 'yes'
        else:
           print 'no'
    f(3)
```

Comment: How is this related to OPs question?

Comment: The OP's code was properly indented. Your code raises an `IndentationError`. That doesn't seem like a very good fix to me.

Comment: @abarnert It was more of issue in formtting in SO than the code. I edited it.

Comment: OK, so now the OP's code is properly indented, and so is yours, so instead of breaking the code, you're doing nothing whatsoever?